# iOS app with Gluon, get app in full screen and keep screen alive

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I am making a simple iOS application with two Views using gluon. In one of the views I need to be able to keep screen alive indefinitely, prevent it from rotating and have it full screen without the status bar showing. The other View should have the default behaviour(rotating normally, let screen go off when there is no touch input by the user and status bar should be showing).
I have seen some tutorials on how to do this on Android binding an interface to native code. Is this possible to do in iOS? I have looked around everywhere online and no one seems to have done this. Any pointers ? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the Charm Down [services](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down)? For instance the [video service](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/153d43c06ff129f1ff93cc48a030c3a2cf099281/plugins/plugin-video/?at=default) has implemented for both Android and iOS full screen and keep screen alive. Once you see how it works, you should be able to implement all the features you request.

Comment: thank you very much Jose. No I didn't notice that the video service was already doing that. I will check the link.